# More efficient way to choose a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Python script that lets me choose what function to do (for example, clean the downloads folder or download videos). All of these cases have a separate script which I import into the main .py file. The way I currently have it set up, I get the input and then if it's 1 then execute the first function, if it's 2 execute the second function and so on. Here's my code currently:

```
    if action == 1:
        instagram_downloader()
        print("Done")
    elif action == 2:
        clean_downloads()
        print("Done")
```

While this isn't too bad for a small amount of functions, once I get into double digits it will get messy and inefficient.
Is there a better and more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Use a dictionary: `functions = {1: instagram_downloader, 2: clean_downloads}` and then `functions[action]()`.

Comment: Related: [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60208/4518341)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use a dict. That's Python's equivalent of a case/switch-statement in other languages.

```
functions = {1: instagram_downloader, 2: clean_downloads}
function = functions[action]
function()
```